# SQL request does not work correctly

Tags: mysql, cakephp, request

my problem is very simple. I have a table named 'articles' and I'd like to get the first three recent articles order DESC. But I want also these articles be displayed if their publication date is older or equal to today. So I've had an other condition in my request. My cakephp code is the following :

```
$this->set('lastArticles', $this->Article->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Article.visible' => true),
            'Article.publication_date <= ' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'order' => array('Article.creation_date DESC', 'Article.id DESC'),
            'limit' => 3
        )));
```

But the problem is even if the articles with a publication date > date('Y-m-d') these ones are displayed too! Does anyone have an idea ? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your publication_date condition isn't in the conditions array.  Your code should look like this:

```
$this->set('lastArticles', $this->Article->find('all', 
     array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Article.visible' => true, 
            'Article.publication_date <= ' => date('Y-m-d')
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Article.creation_date DESC', 
            'Article.id DESC'
        ),
        'limit' => 3
    )));
```

A bit of extra indentation and whitespace is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution and it does not work. Nevertheless the publication date of the article is 2012-07-31 so it should not be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

```
See this

$conditions = array(
                'Article.visible' => true,
                'Article.publication_date <= ' => date('Y-m-d')
            );

$order = array('Article.creation_date DESC', 'Article.id DESC');

$lastArticles = $this->Article->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'order' => $order,
            'limit' => 3
        );

$this->set('lastArticles', $lastArticles);
```